# ではと - is this a particle?

Tags: grammar

> それは、玉座に繋がれた真祖の姫ではなかった。
>   彼女は今でもあの間に繋がれたままである。
>   これは彼女の内面に潜む、彼女と融け合う事を待っている彼女に他ならない。
>   「はじめましてブリュンスタッド。
>   こうしてお話をする機会が回ってくるとは思いませんでした。
>   **なにしろ貴方があの様子では、受け継ぐのは姉君ではと危惧していたものですから」**
>
> This isn't the princess of the true ancestor chained to the throne.
>   She is still chained there.
>   This is what is dwelling inside  her and is waiting to melt with her.
>   Honored to meet you Brunesteid.
>   I did not think I could meet you like this and talk to you.
>   At any rate if you are in that condition, if it's that sister I doubt that inheriting is possible.

Or since he was speaking about waiting to melt I think

> At any rate if you are in that condition, I doubt you can take over your sister.

I think:
ではと
では=Used before a negative consequence or something that is not favourable
と=Quoting particle

I looked for definitions of the words and found that:
受け継ぐ:前の人の仕事などを引き継ぐ。また，人の性質や志などを引き継ぐ。継承する
姉君:姉を敬っていう語。姉上。
危惧:うまくいかないのではないかと，あやぶむこと。危懼

I understand these 3 definitions and I tried my best to understand how the grammar works in the bold sentence.

Edit: I thought 姉君 could be used when addressing older girls
so

> At any rate if you are in that condition, i doubt that for you it's possible

Comment: “ではと= I think:” is a confusing equation. Could you rewrite it to a proper sentence?

Answer (score 2):

> 「受け継ぐのは姉君では」と危惧していた
>   I was worrying that the person who succeeds might be your older sister (instead of you, Brunesteid).

- 受け継ぐの: "the one who succeeds" (i.e., the successor)
- は: topic marker
- 姉君: (honorific) "older sister"
- では: =ではないか; "Isn't it that ～?", "I guess ～?", "perhaps"
- と: quotative particle
- 危惧していた: "I was worrying" (not "I doubt")

Here's more examples:

> - 殺したのはお前だ。  It's you who killed (someone).
> - ケーキを食べたのはお父さんでは?  The one who ate the cake is Dad, I guess?
> - 悪いのは誰だ!?  Who is to blame!?
> - 見えないのでは。  Perhaps you can't see it.
> - うまくいかないのでは（ないか）。 I guess this won't go well.
> - うまくいかないのでは（ないか）とあやぶむ to worry, thinking "this may not go well"

Comment: So の can be used with the meaning of もの(which is used for concrete things) and こと(which is used for abstract things), am I understanding this correctly?