# What’s the difference between “tabun” (たぶん) and “desho” (でしょう)?

Tags: usage

What’s the difference between “[tabun](https://www.tanoshiijapanese.com/dictionary/index.cfm?j=tabun)” (たぶん) and “[desho](https://www.tanoshiijapanese.com/dictionary/entry_details.cfm?entry_id=778&j=desho)” (でしょう). Both mean “probably”, but when would you use one over the other? Please explain by referring to the following examples:

Example 1

> たぶん、黒とグレーです。
>   **Tabun, kuro to guree desu.**
>   (It is probably black and gray.)

Example 2:

> 私たちがうわさをしているのではと彼女が心配するでしょう。
>   **Watashi tachi ga uwasa o shite iru no dewa to kanojo ga shinpai suru deshou.**
>   (She will probably worry if we are gossiping about her)

Please note: I am a beginner and so would appreciate a simplified explanation. Thanks!

Comment: Is "She will probably worry **if** we are gossiping about her" your own translation? It seems a little off.

Comment: @user3856370 What would the correct one be? Thanks!

Comment: That  と is the quotative particle rather than the conditional. The では is a bit subtle for me to translate, but these links should help: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29971/%e3%81%a7%e3%81%af%e3%81%a8-is-this-a-particle and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29121/question-about-usage-of-%e3%81%ae%e3%81%a7%e3%81%af

Comment: I think this のでは refers to possibility so it is in agreement with でしょう. But, as @user3856370 points out, **if** is not the proper word here. In translating to English, the *possibility of gossiping* can be given in an implied tone, or it can be directly stated. I translate this as: *She's worried that we are probably gossiping about her.* or *She's worried that we could be gossiping about her.*

Comment: Yes, the と is quotative... You can rephrase the sentence as: 「"私たちがうわさをしているのでは（ないか？）"と、彼女が心配するでしょう。」 "She will be worried that we might be gossiping..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am a native speaker of Japanese but not of English. So my English may not be natural but I hope to be helpful.

たぶん and でしょう have similar meanings but are different parts of speech.

たぶん（=おそらく）'s definition is:

> [たぶん](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%9F%E3%81%B6%E3%82%93/#je-46615)
>   1 〔おそらく〕probably; perhaps; possibly; maybe

So たぶん is an adverb like *probably*, *perhaps*, or *possibly*. And たぶん’s meaning varies from *probably* to *possibly* according to contexts.

でしょう（=だろう）’s definition is:

> [だろう](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%A0%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86/#je-46845)
>   1 〔推量〕
>   (1)〔話者を主語にして〕I think [suppose/guess] (that).... 
>   [...]
>   (3)〔推量の助動詞を用いて〕

推量の助動詞 means *can be*, *may be*, *could be*, *will be*, etc.

So でしょう is an (auxiliary) verb like *think*, *suppose*, *guess*, *will be*, or *may be*.

Therefore you can say:

> 明日はたぶん雨だ。 (It probably rains tomorrow.)
>   明日は雨でしょう。 (It will rain tomorrow.)
>   明日はたぶん雨でしょう。 (It will probably rain tomorrow. Or I think it probably rains tomorrow.)

(I quoted the definitions from [プログレッシブ和英中辞典](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/je/))

Comment: @suzuki Thanks! So you would only use `deshou でしょう` to clarify that it is your thought? Whereas `“tabun” (たぶん)` is supposed to be less of a guess and implying an element of facts?

Comment: Yes, exactly! As more examples, “彼は勝つ” is “He wins”, “彼は勝つでしょう” is “He will win”, and “彼は多分勝つでしょう” is “Probably he will win”.

Answer (score 3):

たぶん and でしょう belong to different word classes, and it's hard to directly compare them. たぶん is an adverb, and でしょう is a "form of です" that inherently has a speculative/inferential meaning. Asking about the difference between them is like asking about "probably" and "I suppose". Actually, you can safely use both たぶん and でしょう in one sentence:

> **たぶん**彼は心配する**でしょう**。
>   He will probably worry. / I suppose he will worry.

The English word "probably" is an adverb, so you can say たぶん is closer to "probably". You can think でしょう is a way to express a similar idea without using an adverb. Finally, でしょう has various functions, so you may want to review the use of でしょう in a longer article like [this](http://selftaughtjapanese.com/2014/02/19/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%81%86-%E3%81%A0%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86-deshoudarou-in-japanese/).